# Is there a way to view added constraints in Gurobi (Python)?

Tags: linear-programming, python, gurobi

I should note that I am very new to Gurobi so apologies if this is obvious. I am working on a project for a class to maximize profit on a theoretical flight network by deciding which routes to fly at what time and with what type of plane using a linear program. However, I keep running into a problem where there aren't any feasible solutions, but it doesn't seem like there should be interfering constraints from what I can tell. I used a loop to add all of the constraints, and I suspect the problem lies with the way I set the loop up. Is there a way to output a list of all the added constraints? It would be a very helpful way to troubleshoot.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Gurobi has some nice videos and tutorials for beginners which can be useful. you could check your loop definition using these materials. Would you see them? (E.g. [this](https://www.gurobi.com/resource/modeling-with-the-gurobi-python-interface/) or [this](https://www.gurobi.com/resource/modeling-examples/) links) . Also, the answer that @Marco mentioned is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes computing an IIS helps addressing the source of the infeasibility in the model.

Example Usage:

```
model.computeIIS()
model.write("model.ilp")
```

https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_model_computeiis.html
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/examples/diagnose_and_cope_with_inf.html

Answer (score 4):

what I typically do for debugging purposes is to output the model to a file in a "readable" format like LP format using

`model.write("myfile.lp")`